# How to convert entire array of numbers stored as strings in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I trying to learn how to create prototypes in Javascript, but the Array prototype confuses me. I have an Array of Numbers that are stored in the Array as Strings, and I want to convert the entire Array so they are actual numbers. How do I do this an exactly what would I type to activate this prototype?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with prototypes. Is there something specific you meant by that?

Comment: I would disagree with musicfreak and say that the problem is entirely Protoype(ific), though as Matthew points out, in this case you'd be writing a redundant feature of the Array class.  However, it's a great place to practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to use prototypes.  But a simple way to get an array of numbers from an array of strings is:

```
var numArray = strArray.map(parseFloat);
```

For browsers that don't support ECMAScript 5, you can get a fallback implementation of map from [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

## The `prototype` object

The idea of the `prototype` object is that it is an object off which all new objects of that type will get their methods and properties off. By adding to the `prototype` of a predefined object, such as an `Array` or `String`, whenever a new object of that type is created, all of the methods and properties you defined to it's `prototype` will be copied to the new object.

### How do I do it?

To do it, you simply follow the notation `Object.prototype.myProperty = value`, so in your case you want to add a method which converts the entire array of Strings into numbers, here is a simple example of how you would do it:

#### Example

```
//So here, you see the definition of your new method
//Note the use of the 'Object.prototype.property = value' notation
Array.prototype.stringsToNumbers = function()
    { //I use the Whitesmiths indentation style, get over it :p

    //To refer to the object which the method was called on use the
    //'this' keyword.
    for (index in this)
        {
        if (typeof(this[index]) === 'string') //Always typecheck... Always.
            {
            this[index] = parseFloat(this[index]);
            }
        }

    //Sometimes you want to return the object to allow for chaining.
    return this;
    }

//You would then use it like this:
var myArray = ["23","11","42"];
myArray.stringsToNumbers();
//myArray now contains [23,11,42]
```

### What else should I be aware of?

Arguably, the largest danger of prototyping native objects is that there creates a chance of collisions with other third party code, especially when extending the native objects with relatively common methods, such as `Array.prototype.empty()`. Take this into account while prototyping native objects, especially with the naming of your methods and properties. Consider adding a prefix to the method if you believe there is a chance of a collision, so use `Array.prototype.mylibEmpty()` instead.